# Definining parameters in F# functions, is it better using tuples?

Tags: f#, parameters, parameter-passing

A simple question... Is it good practice to define a function accepting more than 1 parameter through tuples?

I explain myself better:
I have a function:

```
let myfunc par1 par2 = ...;;
```

Is it good to to so?

```
let myfunc (par1, par2) = ...;;
```

When I say "is it good" I am saying: is it good practice? is it good to do this ALWAYS as a common practice to pass parameters to a function??

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normal F# style is to define functions curried, i.e. non-tupled according to your first example.

Currying lets you do this: ("partial application")

```
let myfunc par1 par2 = ...
let myfuncHello = myfunc "Hello"
myfuncHello "World" // same as: myfunc "Hello" "World"
```

However, if you expose your code to .NET languages other than F#, stick with tupling, since it's hard to call curried functions except from F#.

**Edit:** from the brand new F# Snippets site: http://fssnip.net/I

Comment: Ah ok... now I can see where is useful tupled notation... ah one question sorry: so the first notation is called currying? (I still cannot accept your answer because I must wait 5 mins :) ).

Comment: That's right: in the first notation, you've defined a curried function; myfunc is curried. When you call it like I did in my answer, you've partially applied it. These terms are commonly confused: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application

Comment: Yeah i've read it right before, it's very cool currying... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andry Currying was always my favourite part of Haskell, glad F# included it, partially at least.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: I was reading recently that there were some aspects F# did not cater for, curried type constructors possibly? I forget.

Comment: @Orbling That's true: in F# (and OCaml), discriminated union constructors are tupled not curried.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: I'm sure they had good reason for the decision.